# List of nodes within a block

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I have a page for available job positions, which has some content but I'd like to also place a list of the jobs in the middle of this content.

[image: screenshot]

I would like this list to be dynamic based on currently published "job" nodes. The problem is this content is within a block. I know about views and can easy create a list with views, but I don't want this list to be a stand-alone block. Is there a way to pull a dynamic list like this into a pre-made block?

Comment: there are multiple ways to do this
1. you can create a view page with list of nodes and you can add other content in the views header or footer area.
2. you can create it as view attachment and can add to other view.
Basically views have a great flexibility to  get embedded in one another,panels, nodes etc.

Comment: @arpitr using views attachment is a good answer, your comment should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. You can create a view page with list of nodes and you can add other
   content in the views header or footer area.
2. You can create it as view attachment and can add to other view.

Basically views have a great flexibility to get embedded in one another,panels, nodes etc.